# php can't decrypt the cipher from $_get request on RNCryptor

Tags: php, encryption, rncryptor

I am trying to decrypt the cipher which i take from my jailbroken iphone but I don't know why the RNCryptor decrypt function always return null value when I put the $_get value to function, but it is worked fine when I put the raw data to decrypt function. Anyone have idea about this problem?
This is the code which is return null value:

```
if(isset($_GET['info'])){

    $password = "mykey"
    $base64Encrypted = $_GET['info'];
    $cryptor = new \RNCryptor\Decryptor();
    $plaintext = $cryptor->decrypt($base64Encrypted, $password);
    echo $plaintext;//=> this code block return null value

}else{
    echo 'not have info params';
}
```

But when i put raw cipher data this codeblock running well:

```
if(isset($_GET['info'])){

    $password = "mykey"
    $base64Encrypted = 'AwEEeG/CU0VHXVGvuRcm805DvvVQi32NPjmlQxoaniIL9ngCjNY1Su4jEb2IfCILBvhKIdjl1znysm6SMiFmRZi2St8wCcWCmnImdwAPLysB/g==';
    $cryptor = new \RNCryptor\Decryptor();
    $plaintext = $cryptor->decrypt($base64Encrypted, $password);
    echo $plaintext;//=> this code block return the original value of cipher

}else{
    echo 'not have info params';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just firgure out that the $_get param just being encoded when send through URL so all '+' character has been change to space character. This is my solution:

```
 $password = "mykey";
    $stringCipher = explode('?info=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
    $base64Encrypted = $stringCipher[1];
    $cryptor = new \RNCryptor\Decryptor();
    $decryptSerial = $cryptor->decrypt($base64Encrypted, $password);
```